# SetActive can only be called from the main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

hey im making a multiplayer game in unity using tcp protocol im using a new thread with loop for checking if there is message to receive

```
Thread ctThread = new Thread(getMessage);
ctThread.Start();

private void getMessage()
{
    while (true)
    {
        int buffSize = 0;
        byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
        buffSize = mySocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
        theStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);
        try
        {
            string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
            checkMessage(returndata);
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

every thing is working fine but when i recive message from the server to change the active canvas or something like this:

```
cnv.SetActive(false);
```

i get this error:

```
SetActive can only be called from the main thread.
```

and not just with SetActive almost with everything i get the same error

Comment: not sure if it's a typo in your actual code or just here, but you seem to have an extra } after the `catch`

Comment: I don't think you can use Unity-specific functions from outside of the main thread.

Comment: @ryemoss i fixed it

Comment: @Serlite so what should i do ?

Comment: You can only call `SetActive()` from the main thread, you need [interthread communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460763/interthread-communication)

Comment: @Draco18s so what should i do in this case?

Comment: This is a link, you should click it: [interthread communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460763/interthread-communication).

Comment: @Draco18s it desn't help me