# Syntax for adding an event handler in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, event-handling, c#-to-vb.net

I have following code i need to convert to VB.NET. Problem is every translation tool I found is converting the add handler part wrong. I don't seem to be able to do it by myself.

```
FtpClient ftpClient = new FtpClient();
ftpClient.UploadProgressChanged += new EventHandler<UploadProgressChangedLibArgs>(ftpClient_UploadProgressChanged);
ftpClient.UploadFileCompleted += new EventHandler<UploadFileCompletedEventLibArgs>(ftpClient_UploadFileCompleted);
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are two different ways to associate event handler methods with an event in VB.NET.

The first involves the use of the `Handles` keyword, which you append to the end of the event handler method's definition. For example:

```
Sub ftpClient_UploadProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As UploadProgressChangedLibArgs) Handles ftpClient.UploadProgressChanged
    ' ...
End Sub

Sub ftpClient_UploadFileCompleted(sender As Object, e As UploadFileCompletedEventLibArgs) Handles ftpClient.UploadFileCompleted
    ' ...
End Sub
```

The first method is much simpler if you've already got separately defined event handler methods anyway (i.e., if you're not using a lambda syntax). I would recommend it whenever possible.

The second involves the explicit use of the `AddHandler` statement, just like `+=` in C#. This is the one you need to use if you want to associate event handlers *dynamically*, e.g. if you need to change them at run time. So your code, literally converted, would look like this:

```
Dim ftpClient As New FtpClient()
AddHandler ftpClient.UploadProgressChanged, AddressOf ftpClient_UploadProgressChanged
AddHandler ftpClient.UploadFileCompleted, AddressOf ftpClient_UploadFileCompleted
```

Like you said, I tried running your code through [Developer Fusion's converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) and was surprised to see that they were returning invalid VB.NET code:

```
' WRONG CODE!
Dim ftpClient As New FtpClient()
ftpClient.UploadProgressChanged += New EventHandler(Of UploadProgressChangedLibArgs)(ftpClient_UploadProgressChanged)
ftpClient.UploadFileCompleted += New EventHandler(Of UploadFileCompletedEventLibArgs)(ftpClient_UploadFileCompleted)
```

Turns out, that's [a known bug](http://feedback.developerfusion.com/forums/5477-code-converter/suggestions/212793-addhandler) that might be worth voting for!

Comment: i am getting this error now, what does this mean? thanks `Error 1 Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.`

Comment: @Justme Use the Handles keyword at the end of a procedure declaration to cause it to handle events raised by an object variable declared using the **WithEvents** keyword. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/6k46st1y

Comment: thanks for the answer! now its working.. i have another problem tough.. since the uploader is working on another thread, also the sub called by the event is executed on another thread. can i force that one to be run on the main thread? i need it to access the interface..

Comment: @Just To run code on the UI thread or interact with controls, use the `Invoke` method. Lots of information about this here already, for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356/cleanest-way-to-invoke-cross-thread-events).

Comment: and how would `  Public Event UploadProgressChanged As EventHandler(Of UploadProgressChangedLibArgs)` be set to a correct sentence? online its still covnerting wrong.. thanks